# Solve the Laplace's equation in the domain $D = \{(x, y) : x > 0, 0 < y < h\}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Solve the Laplace's equation in the domain $D = \{(x, y) : x > 0, 0 < y < h$} subject to the boundary conditions $u(x, 0) = 0 = u(x, h)\, \, \forall x > 0$, $u(x, y) \rightarrow 0$ as $ x \rightarrow 0 $ and $u(0, y) = 2\pi $ for $ 0 < y < h$.

My work:  By separation of variable $\frac{X^{''}}{X} = -\frac{Y^{''}}{Y} = \mu$

we also have

$u(x, 0) = X(x)Y(0) = 0 \, \ \Rightarrow Y(0) = 0 \\
u(x, h) = X(x)Y(h) = 0 \, \ \Rightarrow Y(h) = 0 \\
u(0, y) = X(0)Y(y) = 2\pi \, \ \Rightarrow X(0) = 2\pi$

Then by solving eigenvalue problem for $\mu > 0$ we have $\mu = \left(\frac{n\pi}{h}\right)^{2}$ and $Y_{n}(y) = b_{n}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{h}\right)$

as $u(x, y) \rightarrow 0$ for $x \rightarrow 0$ we have $X(x) = d_n\sinh\left(\frac{n\pi x}{h}\right)$

Then $u(x, y) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n}\sinh\left(\frac{n\pi x}{h}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{h}\right)$

But if we apply $u(0, y) = 2\pi$, then it create problem, I am not getting answer. Please help.

Comment: Such a condition would lead to a discontinuous function, which cannot be the solution to a differential equation because it is not differentiable. Perhaps it was typo and the third boundary condition meant to say $u(x,y)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$

Comment: may be but in problem it is $x \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Then tough luck. To continue to try to do something after someone has pointed out its impossibility is absurd.

Comment: if I take your suggestion then using $u(0, y) =  2\pi$ , one side of equality $2\pi$ and  other side have the form $\sin(\frac{n\pi y}{h})$. Then how we compute unknown?

Comment: You don't, it's a series. Perhaps there is some choice of constants $a_n$ that will get the desired equality if you think of it as a Fourier series.

Comment: oh, by using orthogonality of $\sin$

Answer (score 1):

Using the alternate condition that $u(x,y)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$, we get the following general solution

$$u(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \exp\left(-\frac{n\pi x}{h}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{h}\right)$$

Then the boundary condition at $x=0$ gives the following Fourier series to solve for

$$u(0,y) \equiv f(y) = 2\pi = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{h}\right)$$

on the interval $y\in[0,h]$. Using periodic boundary conditions, the function is odd so all of the cosine terms vanish. The sine terms are

$$a_n = \frac{2}{h}\int_0^h 2\pi \sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{h}\right)dy = \begin{cases}\frac{8}{n} & n \hspace{4 pt} \text{odd} \\ 0 & n \hspace{4 pt} \text{even} \\ \end{cases}$$

Leaving us with a final answer (after reindexing) of

$$u(x,y) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{8}{2k+1}\exp\left(-\frac{(2k+1)\pi x}{h}\right)\sin\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi y}{h}\right)$$